# Should I change the entire scene or just the parts I need?

Tags: javafx

I want to create the following design for my app. Note that there's an AppBar on top and some content below it wrapped on a ScrollPane. The icons at the left would change the content shown, taking the user to different sections of the app, e.g: browsing documents, messages, settings, etc. The AppBar at the top would still be the same, only the content in the middle would change. Now there's two ways to do it:

- Having a single screen with a ScrollPane, whose children is changed dynamically, so every time an icon is pressed the child changes.
- Having multiple screens, when the user clicks an icon, an entire new scene is created.

What are the pros and cons of doing it each way?

[image]

Comment: You probably should not be using `ScrollPane`. I think it's fine if you only have a few items to display, but `ListView` is normally used in these situations. When memory is little and limited `ListView` is key. If this is a mobile app, I would suggest changing to `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to manage with one Scene. This is typical use case in JavaFX applications with BorderPane. You can create a AppView extends BorderPane and set the Menu/Toolbar in top, your opened View in center and status bar (if you use) in bottom. If requested, you can change only current view in the center of BorderPane.

I have implemented similar AppView, you can check [AppView](https://bitbucket.org/devsniper/customersfx/src/master/src/main/java/com/cemikta/customersfx/view/AppView.java) in my JavaFX MVC application demo source code.